# Architecture/logic issue- how do I rebuild only ONE Consumer widget in this scenario? - Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, architecture, consumer, riverpod

I really backed myself into a corner & have no idea how to re-design to fix this smoothly while keeping my functionality. I tried moving the reusable widget up in the tree but that was confusing and didn't work. I'm working on creating a Flutter package, in case this may incite some help. This is a question specific to my erroneous architecture/logic but also a general question as to how to create re-usable widgets with Riverpod provider so as to update ONLY necessary widget.

My problem is I have a "reusable" widget - "NumberButtonAnimation" & I have 5 of them in my "SequentialNavigator" parent in this case. They are all buttons and they are all listening to the pageIndex value in my logic services file navigatorServices. So when the page index is changed they all rebuild which is expensive and unnecessary of course.

How can I add logic or re-design so that only the moving button needs rebuild?

Would I be correct in my thinking if I thought keys could be of some use?

```
/// LOGIC

final navigatorServices = ChangeNotifierProvider((ref) => NavigatorServices());

class NavigatorServices extends ChangeNotifier {
  StateCRUD stateCRUD = StateCRUD();
  int pageIndex = 1;
  int indexCount = 5;

  void nextPage() {
    if (pageIndex < indexCount) {
      pageIndex++;
      saveState();
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  void previousPage() {
    if (pageIndex > 1) {
      pageIndex--;
      saveState();
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  double buttonPosition(int buttonNumber) {
    double totalHeight = Get.height;
    double topPadding = WidgetsBinding.instance!.window.padding.top;
    double bottomPadding = WidgetsBinding.instance!.window.padding.bottom;
    double safeArea = totalHeight - (topPadding + bottomPadding);
    const double buttonWithPadding = 35.0;
    late double buttonTop;
    List<int> pageIndexes = [];
    int index = 0;
    // Current or past screen
    if (pageIndex >= buttonNumber) buttonTop = ((buttonWithPadding * buttonNumber) - buttonWithPadding);
    if (pageIndex < buttonNumber) {
      while (index < indexCount + 1) {
        pageIndexes.add(index);
        index++;
      }
      buttonTop = (buttonWithPadding * pageIndexes[buttonNumber]) + safeArea / 1.5;
    }
    return buttonTop;
  }

   ...
}


/// NUMBER BUTTON ANIMATION WIDGET

class NumberButtonAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
  const NumberButtonAnimation({Key? key, required this.buttonNumber}) : super(key: key);
  final int buttonNumber;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer(
      builder: (context, ref, child) {
        print('Number button consumer built');
        return AnimatedPositioned(
          top: ref.watch(navigatorServices).buttonPosition(buttonNumber),
          curve: Curves.bounceOut,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          child: NumberButton(number: buttonNumber),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

/// PARENT WIDGET

class SequentialNavigator extends StatelessWidget {
  const SequentialNavigator({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 43.0,
      height: double.maxFinite,
      child: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        children: [
          const NumberButtonAnimation(buttonNumber: 1),
          const NumberButtonAnimation(buttonNumber: 2),
          const NumberButtonAnimation(buttonNumber: 3),
          const NumberButtonAnimation(buttonNumber: 4),
          const NumberButtonAnimation(buttonNumber: 5),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What it looks like when I tap next or previous once:

`<5> flutter: Number button consumer built`

This prints 5 times indicating all widgets rebuilding but only one button needs rebuilding on any change...

Comment: Have you considered converting `NumberButtonAnimation` to a `Stateful` widget? It provides access to conditionally rebuild: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html

Comment: I fail to see how that could solve my problem. I am setting state through a consumer by listening for changes. There is no control flow that I can see enabling such a fix. If there was then it could be done with stateless too. Is there a way to notifyListeners() for specific widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `provider.select(...)` to filter rebuilds by obtaining only what you need

A usage example would be:

```dart
Consumer(
  builder: (context, ref, child) {
    print('Number button consumer built');
    return AnimatedPositioned(
      top: ref.watch(navigatorServices.select((service) => service.buttonPosition(buttonNumber)),
      ...
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: This works perfectly as I need and want. Thank you Remi. I appreciate the simplicity of this package!